# Loss of color when resizing images

Tags: java, image, colors, awt, bufferedimage

I am using this method to change image size:

```
private File resize(double scale, File file) throws IOException {
    double scaledSize = targetSize * scale;
    BufferedImage scaledImage = Scalr.resize(sourceImage, (int) scaledSize);

    Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(fileExt);
    ImageWriter writer = iter.next();
    ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    iwp.setCompressionQuality(1);

    FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(file);
    writer.setOutput(output);
    IIOImage image = new IIOImage(scaledImage, null, null);
    writer.write(null, image, iwp);
    writer.dispose();
    return file;
}
```

It seems images lose color depth. How can I set same color depth as source image?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   Hot-link to a small (in bytes) image.